# Evento click en JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy aprendiendo a usar JQuery y por alguna razon, cuando hago referencia al evento click, aparece tachado y no se ejecuta.

El documento JS es este:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Seleccionar ID
    var rojo = $("#rojo"); 
    //Metodos
    rojo
        .css("background", "red")
        .css("color", "white");

    var amarillo = $("#amarillo");
    amarillo
        .css("background", "yellow") //Cambia propiedades css
        .css("color", "red");

    var verde = $("#verde").css("background", "green").css("color", "white");

    var zebra = $(".zebra").css("background", "black").css("color", "white");
    

    $(".clase").click(function () {//click me sale tachado aqui
        $(this).addClass("zebra");
    });
});
```

Y esto es lo que está en el body del HTML

```
<h1>JQuery</h1>
        <p id="rojo">Ejercicios de Jquery</p>
        <p id="amarillo">Practicando con selectores</p>
        <p id="verde">Texto de relleno</p>

        <p class="clase">Presioname</p>

        <p class="zebra">Texto zebra</p>
        <p class="zebra">Texto zebra</p>
        <p class="zebra">Texto zebra</p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery.js"></script>
```

Todos los p funcionan bien, pero el que debe responder al click ignora.

Comment: A que te refieres con que lo ignora? en tu codigo `$(this).addClass("zebra");`  agregale un color para que veas el cambio. algo asi `$(this).addClass("zebra").css("color", "red");`

Comment: Los IDE suelen marcar algo *tachándolo* cuando está *obsoleto*, o como se suele decir, *deprecated*. Es decir, que estás usando una versión de jQuery en la que ya [no se recomienda usar `.click()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/main/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfnclick-event-shorthand-is-deprecated), lo correcto es usarlo así: `.on("click", function () {/*Tu código aquí*/});`

Answer (score 2):

una manera de solucionarlo es que en tu evento click al elemento primero remuevas la clase existente y agregues la clase zebra, ahora como la clase zebra no esta definida como un elemento css deberas indicar nuevamente que todos los elementos-zebra tengan fondo negro y texto blanco.

```
     $(".clase").on("click",  function () {

        $(this).removeClass("clase");
        $(this).addClass("zebra");
        $(".zebra").css("background", "black").css("color", "white");
});
```

Comment: El usuario indica que le sale tachado el método `.click()`, el cual se encuentra deprecado desde jQuery 3.0. En tu respuesta, sigues empleando el método `.click()` así que un IDE que reconozca la versión de jQuery te lo va a seguir tachando, puesto que sigue estando deprecado...

Comment: Ok, @Benito-B modifique de acuerdo a tu comentario gracias